# Puedo mover mis repositorios .git a un parent folder sin perder el historial? Cual es la mejor manera de hacerlo?

Tags: git

Tengo una carpeta con varios repositorios que me gustarìa organizar moviendo varios de estos repositorios a una nueva carpeta que los nuclee.

Puedo moverlos sin màs y hacer git add . y git commit? Perderìa el historial de cambios o ocasionarìa algùn problema? (por ejemplo para hacer rollbacks a commits que sucedieron antes de este cambio).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes moverlos sin mas pero en dicho caso perderás todo el historial.
Para ello el proceso sería borrar la carpeta .git y mover las carpetas donde quieras..

Dicho eso hay otra forma de hacerlo. Suponiendo que tienes 3 repos: `a` `b` y `c` y quieres añadir `b` y `c` como subcarpetas de `a` y llamarlas del mismo modo

```
git subtree add --prefix=b git://github.com/b.git master
git subtree add --prefix=c git://github.com/c.git master
```

Si las carpetas están todas en tu pc lo puedes hacer usando `file:///ruta/repo`
De esta forma solo copiarás master perdiendo todas las demás ramas.

Y la última y más completa sería usar `filter-repo`

Aquí hay un [ejemplo con ruby y bundler](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/9890ab1079cf4357d6f269d073fd9731) que creo que lo deja bastante claro.